# Overnight layover in Toronto as of early June 2020?

Tags: canada, layovers, covid-19

I'm considering booking a flight from the US to Germany to tend to a family emergency. The connection that I'm currently looking at has an overnight layover in Toronto. Is it possible to use this connection under current circumstances?

To the extent that it matters, I'm a German citizen with a Canadian work permit living in Canada, but have spent the past few months of lockdown in the US. As a temporary resident, I believe that I would be able to enter Canada under current regulations. But returning travellers to Canada are subject to two weeks of quarantine. However, is transit with an overnight layover still possible?

I'd be spending the night at an airport hotel, or inside the airport if necessary.

Comment: I’d think you’d have to call security at the specific airport, and just in case you get someone who is mistaken, call again three or four hours later.  And then hope the policy doesn’t change before the flight!

Comment: Safest approach is probably to look for a nonstop flight, and bother the expense.

Comment: @WGroleau: thank you for the two useful suggestions. There doesn't seem to be a nonstop flight available, but a more expensive option with layover still in the US may work. I'll look into that.

Comment: @CanAdian:  You could try broadening your searches to multiple days.  Many long-haul flights still exist, but operate only once or twice a week.

Comment: You can try calling (1) CBSA at 1-800-461-9999 and (2) contact Toronto airport (1-866-207-1690 or their FB) and the airline to check if you can transfer without leaving secured area; also (3) COVID information line 1-833-784-4397 from the public health agency (or email phac.covid19.aspc@canada.ca) for information on exemptions to quarantine requirements.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.